# C++ Size of classes and subclasses

Tags: c++, oop, memory

If a class instance uses 20 bytes, and its subclass uses 24 bytes since it as more members, how is it possible to store an instance of the subclass in a variable of the parent class?

Like:

```
Subclass s;
ParentClass p ;
p = s;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't "store" instances "in" pointers. Pointers merely *point at the start* of the instance in memory.

The pointer object itself contains a memory address, and the space that this takes up is always the same no matter what — or how much — data may be found at that address.

---

**Edit** *(since the question has changed almost completely)*

In the example you've added to your question, the code doesn't do what you think it does. You are not storing a `Subclass` in a `ParentClass`; instead, you are slicing off the derived bits of `s`, and copying only its base bits into `p`.

You asked elsewhere how you can fit a `Derived` in an array of `Base`; *you can't*.

Answer (score 6):

The pointer size is always identical. It just points to a larger memory region.

Compare:

```
+-----+
| ptr | ------+
+-----+       |
              v
              +----------+
              | Base     |
              +----------+
```

with:

```
+-----+
| ptr | ------+
+-----+       |
              v
              +----------+----+
              | Derived       |
              +----------+----+
```

Where the pointer value in both cases is some fictional address which marks the start address of the memory region that hosts the respective object.

Comment: Might I suggest making the arrow come up vertically to the start of the memory block, for clarity. And I think the `Derived` label is possibly misleading there. (Fit, though!)

Comment: But if the amount of memory allocated was the amount needed to store the parent class how does the derived fits? I'm writing a memory allocator so if I request 20 bytes and I store 24 bytes some memory belonging to other objects will be overwritten...

Comment: For example: If I create an array of base class objects how can I store instances of the derived class in it?

Comment: @Tiago: See my answer. There is no "fitting". The pointer is 4 bytes (or 8 bytes, or some other number, depending on your system), not 24. However, if you're writing a memory allocator that, for an object of type `Derived` is allocating `sizeof(Base)` rather than `sizeof(Derived)` bytes then, yes, your allocator is completely broken.

Comment: If you create an array of base class objects, you _cannot_ store instances of the derived class in it. Obviously. The best you can do is to store _pointers_ instead, which always take up `sizeof(void*)` bytes. The pointers can, individually, point to memory blocks of any size.

Answer (score 2):

Class instances (i.e. objects) are not stored in pointers. They just occupy memory, subclass instances in general more than class instances. Pointers - as the name says - only point to these objects in memory. The pointer can be compared to an address of a memory block. And the address occupies always the same amount of bytes.